# SQL Server : join on 4-5 tables with different structures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables

- Employee
- ApprovalMatrix
- ExpenseMatrix

`Employee` contains:

```
ID  CompanyId  Name
---------------------------------------
9   1          ABC  
10  1          XYZ
11  1          WEW
```

`ApprovalMatrix`  contains:

```
ID      Module  Employeeid   EmployeeLeaderId
--------------------------------------------
11      M1         9            11 
12      M1         10           11 
13      M2         9            11 
55      M3         10           11 
56      M2         10           11
```

`ExpenseMatrix` contains:

```
ID   Employeeid   EmployeeLeaderId
--------------------------------------------
11      10           9
12      11           9
```

Expected result:

```
Module  EmployeeName   EmployeeLeaderName
--------------------------------------------
M1          ABC            WEW 
M1          XYX            WEW 
M2          ABC            WEW 
M3          XYZ            WEW 
M2          XYZ            WEW 
Expense     XYZ            ABC
Expense     WEW            ABC
```

Like this I have 4-5 different tables need to merge all tables Employee wise, also need module name for which module leader is assigned.

Below is the query I have tried so far

```
select 
    C.Module, A.Employeeid, B.Name 
from 
    Employee  B 
join 
    ExpenseMatrix A on A.EmployeeLeaderId = B.Id
join 
    ApprovalMatrix C on C.EmployeeLeaderId = B.Id
where 
    B.EmpStatus = 1 and A.EmployeeId = 56
```

Comment: what is the issue here, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Side note: you should use **more meaningful** table alias - just A, B, and C are really not helpful - use `Employee E`, `ExpenseMatrix EM` and `ApprovalMatrix AM` and your JOIN conditions become a lot clearer: `on EM.EmployeeLeaderId = E.Id` etc.

Comment: last two records expected came from an union, not a join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    A.Module, e1.name, e2.Name 
from 
    ApprovalMatrix AM
inner join  Employee  E1
    on AM.EmployeeId = E1.ID
inner join  Employee  E2
    on AM.EmployeeLeaderId = E2.ID
union all
select 'Expense', e1.name, e2.name
From ExpenseMatrix EM
inner join  Employee  E1
    on EM.EmployeeId = E1.ID
inner join  Employee  E2
    on EM.EmployeeLeaderId = E2.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi try below code .

```
;with temp as
(select Module , Employeeid  , EmployeeLeaderId from ApprovalMatrix 
union all 
select 'Expence' as Module  ,Employeeid , EmployeeLeaderId from ExpenseMatrix ) 

select Module, b.Name as  EmployeeName ,c.name as  EmployeeLeaderName  from temp a
left join Employee b on a.EmployeeLeaderId =b.Id
left join Employee c  on a.EmployeeLeaderId =c.id
```

Note Add more table in union all in CTE block.

Comment: ExpenseMatrix  does not have module

Comment: Correct your query please, concept is good, voted your answer